# ClickHouse: how to select some fields as JSON-object

Tags: json, clickhouse

ClickHouse query:

```sql
select ( select 1 as c11, 'ab' as c12, 78 as c13 ) as c1, 'ooo' as c2
format JSONEachRow
```

returns:

```
{"c1":[1,"ab",78],"c2":"ooo"}
```

Is it possible to get **c1** as an object instead of an array? :

```
{"c1":{"c11":1,"c12":"ab","c13":78},"c2":"ooo"}
```

Format JSONEachRow is mandatory.

Comment: You should use code block to show your piece of code for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. The result of select-subquery is interpreted as a tuple and be output as an array.

As a workaround, the result can be flattened and if required be applied some post-processing.

```sql
SELECT c1.1 AS "c1.c11", c1.2 AS "c1.c12", c1.3 AS "c1.c13", c2
FROM (
  SELECT     
      (SELECT 1, 'ab', 78) AS c1, 
      'ooo' AS c2)
FORMAT JSONEachRow
/* result
{"c1.c11":1,"c1.c12":"ab","c1.c13":78,"c2":"ooo"}
*/
```